# What is this useless thing?

Tags: riddle

We do this , but won't have a clue we did it ,

Sometimes it leads to fantasy , sometimes just nothing ,

Sometimes long , sometimes short ,

It is most useless thing humans are doing from generations ,

What is this useless thing ..?

Comment: Too broad. There are many things that will fit the description, like dream, love etc. You should add more details to make sure the answer will be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that

> A dream ?

We do this , but won't have a clue we did it ,

> We dream , but in morning we forget it

Sometimes it leads to fantasy , sometimes just nothing ,

> self explanatory, sometimes its just a blank dream

Sometimes long , sometimes short ,

> dream's is long and short at times

It is most useless thing humans are doing from generations ,

> Dreams doesnt help us anyway

Answer (score 1):

is it

> sleep?

We do this , but won't have a clue we did it ,

> people don't tend to be conscious when sleeping. it is also true that noone knows exactly why we need to sleep

Sometimes it leads to fantasy , sometimes just nothing ,

> you dream when you sleep, however if you have various substances you might sleep dreamlessly

Sometimes long , sometimes short ,

> You can sleep for hours at night, or shorter during a nap

It is most useless thing humans are doing from generations ,

> Everyone sleeps, in all generations, and noone can do anything while sleeping, making it useless

Comment: Isn't sleeping good for health? :)

Comment: Not just good. But is necessary. ;)